# Configuring Redis + Sidekiq in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, passenger, sidekiq

I'm trying to set up **Redis** + **Sidekiq** in a Passenger/Rails production environment and have run into some confusion.

The server has a number of small-ish apps running on it. I'm certain that more than one of these apps will leverage the delayed processing offered by Sidekiq.

My first thought was to use the [namespace option in Sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Advanced-Options) to create a `namespace` for each Rails app.

But then I noticed a `databases 16` setting in `redis.conf` and I'm wondering what that does, exactly. I can't seem to find documentation on it other than the comments in the config:

```
# Set the number of databases. The default database is DB 0, you can select
# a different one on a per-connection basis using SELECT <dbid> where
# dbid is a number between 0 and 'databases'-1
databases 16
```

So, wondering if the default/example of 16 'databases' means that I could use DB0 for one app and DB1 for another app?!? I don't think this assumption is correct but I can't find more information other than:

> Redis Cluster does not support multiple databases like the stand alone
>   version of Redis, there is just database 0, and SELECT is not allowed.

**Hoping someone can advise me on how to share Sidekiq & Redis among various Rails applications running on same server.**

Answer (score 5):

You can use multiple Redis Databases; each one associated with a Rails App on a single machine. You can put a file sidekiq.rb in initializers, with the following code:

```
app_name = Rails.application.class.parent_name

app_num = case app_name
  when 'AppOne'
    0
  when 'AppTwo'
    1
  when 'AppOne'
    2
  end

Redis.new(db: app_num) # existing DB is selected if already present

Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.redis = { url: "redis://localhost:6379/#{app_num}", namespace: "#{app_name}" }
end

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.redis = { url: "redis://localhost:6379/#{app_num}", namespace: "#{app_name}" }
end
```

In this way, You are separating out Redis DBs as well as namespaces by Sidekiq processes.

Comment: That's great, however it would probably be better to get the "app_num" from the environment.  I.e. `app_num = ENV['REDIS_DB_NUM'] || 0`

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for namespaces. You can configure a server/client configuration with sidekiq to use different namespaces and configure Passenger/Unicorn to use a different namespace. I've done it with Unicorn, but there should be an equivalent option in Passenger.

You can find the documentation on how to do this [here](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Advanced-Options).

Comment: Excuse my ignorance but why would Passenger/Unicorn be involved? (FWIW - My production environment uses Passenger)

Comment: If you look at the documentation I linked, there is a block that you need to add to the after_fork callback in Unicorn. I don't know if an equivalent exists for Passenger.

Answer (score 0):

databases 16 in redis.conf simply sets the maximum number of databases Redis instance has (0-15).  You can change it if you want.  I am using Redis DB0 for Rails caching and DB1 for Sidekiq (in addition to using namespaces). Just makes it cleaner in case I need to FLUSHDB.

In your case I would use separate Redis DBs for separate apps.  If need to, just increase the number of databases.